# hiding border of the table

Tags: html, css, html-table

My UI part shows border always. How can I hide that?

```
<div style="float:left; width:100%; height:40px; padding:25px 10px; text-align: left;">
  <div style="padding-left: 260px;">
    <table width="80%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="35%">
          <b>Equipment Type</b>
          <span style="color:red"> *</span> &nbsp;&nbsp; @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClassId, Model.ObjectClasses, "--Select--", new { id = "ddlObjectClass", @onchange = "ClassonChangefunc()", @style = "width:180px" })
        </td>
        <td width="5%"></td>
        <td width="30%">
          <b>Country</b>
          <span style="color:red"> *</span>&nbsp;&nbsp; @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, Model.CountryList, new { data_val = "false", id = "ddlCountry", name = "ddlCountry", @onchange = "CountryChangefunc()", style = "width:200px;" })
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but still the borderline shows...

[image]

What is the easy method to hide that border?

Comment: Can you share working code? because no border showing in this code

Comment: Have you tried adding border:none to your table ? , also try to provide a working example.

Comment: Maybe some styles are applied for this table, try to remove them in CSS. Because by default tables don't have borders.

Comment: Without the relevant CSS for your table, you'll only get broad answers.

Answer (score 1):

Add this styles for this particular table, its rows and cell, i.e. set id for this table (for example `id="table`) then set styles for this table.

```
#table,
#table > tbody > tr,
#table > tbody > tr > td {
  border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change border style of your table

```
table, th, td, tr {
    border-style: none; //!important -> if needed
}
```

Take a look at table (html) & border (css)

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp